# Call a google apps Script from my nodejs server

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script

I've developed a Google Apps Script and published it with no restrictions (everybody can see it), i get an url like this :

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/<scriptid>/exec
```

If i run this in a browser, it runs well.

Now I want to call this from my node js server. I use:

```
request.post({url:url,form:{<my parameters>},function (err,httpResponse,body)
```

The httpResponse replies with a 302 and I've this in the headers:

```
"CP="This is not a P3P policy!
 See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657
```

I believe that I need to do authentication before calling my `request.post`. But was unable to find anywhere in documentation how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for answer, and correction of my poor english writing... finally, i was able to do it client side, with a lot of efforts. I realized that i had to go through an Ajax JSONP request, because my calling domain is still http://<mydomain.com> where Google Apps Script domain  is https://script.google.com. Could this explain the failure trying to do server side ?

Comment: Here my temporary solution above !

Comment: need to learn stackoverflow too.. :-)

Comment: seems that other s.o. answers already cover this by using an apps script contentservice or is there another issue?

Comment: I'm using contentService. I've added the Apps Script in my answer to clarify. The problem was not coming from the script itself, as it was working by entering the url directly in browser. But by the fact i was trying to call it server side.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got a workaround (temporary) :

As it seems that the issue came from domains schemes difference (http on calling side, https Google Apps Script side), solution found was to implement the call client side in the web page, instead of server side, like this :

```
var googleAppsScript = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/<myScriptId>/exec";

function scriptCB(result) { 
    if (result=="KO") displayError("Something went wrong in apps script"); 
    else displayMessage(result); 
} 
function callGAppsScript(docId,fields,cb) { 
    $.ajax({ 
        crossDomain: true, //REQUIRED !! as no scheme matched between my site and script.google.com
        type:'POST', 
        url: googleAppsScript, 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        data: {prefix:'scriptCB',docId:docId,fields:JSON.stringify(fields)}, 
        dataType: "jsonp", //REQUIRED as we do Cross domain
        jsonp:false, //disable adding ?callback= parameter
        jsonpCallback:'scriptCB', //my callback once it is done
        error: function(xhr,status,err) { 
            alert(err); 
        } 
    }); 

}
```

**Google Apps Script being called:**

```
//script to replace some tagged fields in a given doc
function doGet(e) {
  var docId=e.parameter.docId;
  var fields=JSON.parse(e.parameter.fields);
  var doc = openDoc(docId); //my function to open the Google Document
  var result="Document not found :  "+docId;
  if (doc) {
    result="Doc "+doc.getName()+" open. Fields to replace: "+JSON.stringify(fields);
    var _result = replaceFields(doc,fields); //my function to replace fields with new values brought by the external REST call
    if (_result!="KO") result=_result;
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(
    e.parameters.prefix + '(' + JSON.stringify(result) + ')') //this is necessary to get the jsonP callback working.
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT); //that's too.
}

function doPost(e) {
  return doGet(e);
}
```

This works, at the price of this not so nice JSONP technique, waiting i'm putting a certificate on my server, and switch to https://

Comment: Finally, after switching my server to https, no problem to call google app scripts server side. So I confirm : protocol mismatch avoid to call googleApps script server side...